# Should I use negative binomial GAM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to model a data of presence and absence of birds in nest boxes. I look whether it's zero-inflated and it gave me this:

```
Observed zeros: 36
  Predicted zeros: 40
            Ratio: 1.11
```

Is it really worth to make a negative binomial GAM for it? And if yes, what theta should I used or how can I find it out? Thank you in advance!

I made already a binomial GLM for the data and I'm not sure whether it is a good idea

```
Coefficients:
    (Intercept)      In_Temp_avg  Distance_feeder  
      -1.492394         0.134624         0.005013  

Degrees of Freedom: 57 Total (i.e. Null);  55 Residual
Null Deviance:      76.99 
Residual Deviance: 75.35    AIC: 81.35
```

Comment: To clarify, the response variable (nest box occupancy) is **binary** (0/1, present/absent), right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the response variable is binary (0/1, presence/absence) there's really not much you can do other than some form of logistic regression (in R, `glm(..., family="binomial")`; a *negative binomial* model, although it sounds like it should be good for binomial data as well, is for *count* data (0, 1, 2 ...), not for binary data (0/1).

Binary data [can be overdispersed](http://www.highstat.com/Books/BGS/GLMGLMM/pdfs/HILBE-Can_binary_logistic_models_be_overdispersed2Jul2013.pdf), but it's easier to detect if the data can be grouped in some way (e.g., all of your predictors are categorical); it looks like your predictors are continuous, which means it will be harder to investigate (and you can probably get away with not checking :-) ). If you're worried about it you could use a *quasibinomial* model (`family = "quasibinomial"` in R)

Similarly, it doesn't make sense to worry about zero-inflation for binary data: technically speaking, zero-inflation is *unidentifiable* (i.e., there is no way to tell the difference between structural zeros, nest boxes that would *never* have birds in them, and sampling zeros, nest boxes that *happen* not to have birds in them because they have a low probability of occupancy).

A GAM is a *generalized additive model*, which can account for nonlinear patterns in continuous variables. You can fit these easily with `mgcv::gam()`. It might be worth considering this option.

Checking the adequacy of a model for binary data is relatively hard; one way to check the adequacy of your model would be with the [DHARMa package](http://florianhartig.github.io/DHARMa/).

Comment: I don't need to check for "quality" in the data?

Comment: There are a relatively small number of aspects of the data that can be checked for with binary data.